# Бекап файлов сайта

Tags: php, резервное-копирование, exec, tar

Как сделать так чтобы архивировалась полная структура папок сайта?
У меня архивируются только файлы что я выделил на скриншоте.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
$sitedir = 'E:/OpenServer/domains/cms/*';
$filebackup = 'file_backup_'. date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") .'.tar.gz';

shell_exec("tar cvfz $filebackup $sitedir --exclude=$filebackup");
```

Все тестирую на Open server.

Comment: возможно параметры команды неправильные, попробуйте `czf` вместо `cvfz`

Comment: А если `cvzf`?.

Comment: Оба варианта - не помогает. tar вообще может заархивировать всю структуру папок?

Comment: Конечно может--

Comment: Попробовал на рабочем сайте -
shell_exec("tar -cvzf $filebackup $sitedir --exclude=$filebackup");
работает, а на open servere все равно не работает.
Все дело в open server, как я понял (в настройки особо не лазил).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

если файл находитя в папке cms

замени

```
$sitedir = 'E:/OpenServer/domains/cms/*';
```

на

```
$sitedir = '*';
```

и будет архивировать с подпапками

Comment: Вредный совет. Гарантированны проблемы со спецсимволами и слетание POSIX (и не только, раз это винда) прав

Comment: А вот заменять содержимое ответа на полностью другое очень подло

Comment: Да нет. Скрипт лежит внутри ../cms/

Comment: >>А вот заменять содержимое ответа на полностью другое очень подло - не подло так гласят правила данного сайта, вы их читали?

Comment: код выше написанный работает, вы проверяли?..если скрипт в тойже папке просто замените на $sitedir = '*';

Comment: Спасибо, работает но немного не то что ожидал. Подскажите пожалуйста, это ошибка или особенность open server? На рабочем сайте вариант аля /folder1/folder2/folder3/folder_for_backup работает и путь не привязывается к месту скрипта (скрипт можно кинуть куда угодно).